# Change size of /home partition and move /var/www on new partition

Tags: partition, move-partition

I have one issue.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       9.8G  5.8G  3.5G  63% /
udev             11M     0   11M   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.3G  9.5M  1.3G   1% /run
tmpfs           3.2G   74M  3.1G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M  4.1k  5.3M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda6        66G  2.8G   60G   5% /home
tmpfs           628M  4.1k  628M   1% /run/user/117
tmpfs           628M   37k  628M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sr0        3.6G  3.6G     0 100% /media/cdrom0
```

Above is my list of free space and usage on my HDD.

I need more space for web development in `/var/www` and I want to somehow change size of /home partition `/dev/sda1` and made new partition only for `/var/www`

Is that possible?

Comment: Possible, but you could save yourself a lot of trouble by making `/var/www` a symlink to somewhere within `/home`.

Comment: You thinking to move www folder in /home ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jordanm pointed out in a comment, it's much safer to symlink into a new location in an existing partition than to try to resize partitions while keeping their current content.

In your situation, this would be achieved by something like:

```
cd /var
sudo mv -i www /home/
sudo ln -s /home/www .
```

(as a side note: it's usually a good habit to include the `-i` flag to `mv` in order to get a warning message if you're about to overwrite something, especially if you're issuing the `mv` with `sudo`)